# Power in meta-analysis: Determining the number of studies to reach a specific confidence interval width

Tags: confidence-interval, sample-size, statistical-power, meta-analysis, methodology

**Aim:** I would like to do a prospective power-analysis (before data collection) to ***determine the number of studies*** that have to be included in my meta-analysis.

**Data Format:** Heavy-metal concentration in soil and in above-ground plant biomass. My effect size will be a ***Response Ratio*** =  (Heavy Metal Concentration in the Plant/ Heavy Metal Concentration in the Soil), assuming that a ratio of 1 is a “natural zero point”. [Yu et al. (2018)](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-018-19519-3/briefing/signup/?origin=Nature&originReferralPoint=EmailBanner) did a similar analysis and also referred to the plant concentration as the experimental group, and the soil concentration as the control group.

**Power Analysis:** According to [Borenstein (2009)](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/book/10.1002/9780470743386) **a)** "A power analysis can ***focus directly on power*** (the likelihood of a test giving a statistically significant result) OR **b)** may ***focus on precision*** (the likelihood that a confidence interval will be a specific width)." Either approach would work for me, though I would prefer option b).

**a) Power:** As I am working with response ratios (RR), I could state that H0: RR = 1 and HA: RR > 1 or < 1. The R-Scripts I found for power analysis always refer to the *standardized mean difference SMD* or the *Odds ratio OR*.  (e.g. power.analysis in the dmetar package).
***Question 1:*** Is it correct to use the difference between the H0 and HA (e.g. 1.5 – 1 = 0.5) for the standardized mean difference in the R-script? The Odds ratio does not seem to be appropriate, because it is using cross tables?

**b) Precision:** [Liu (2015)](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1177/2168479015570332.pdf) shows a method on how to calculate the needed number of articles to reach a specific precision for the width of the confidence interval. However, this paper gives an example with differences in means, not ratios, and it was only cited a single time (peer-reviewed journal, but no longer published).
***Question 2:*** Would you consider this approach appropriate? Especially depending on which values I plug into his formulas, I get results that already 4 papers included to my meta-analysis should be enough and to me this seems strange. I am confused by the large discrepancy between the two approaches. ***Question 3:*** Do you know any other methods for sample size calculation for the precision of a confidence interval?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Number of articles is irrelevant but rather than the number of samples and observations. Another method is using Trial Sequential Analysis. I know of one group that is developing the methods further that using means and odds ratios/ risk ratios. Not sure what's currently available for use by the public.